# How to make footer area transparent? Using Avada and Wordpress

Tags: images, woocommerce-offtopic, footer

For the homepage, I'd like the main page background to be the background for the entire page, including the footer.

Please help!?

Reed

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It's better if you share the the link to your site OR if you can show us the attempts you have made and the problems which your are facing while doing so.

A suggestion for to do so is to make footer background transparent and apply background image to your .page class which is default wordpress class you can be more specific with by using unique page ID in css and then apply that background.
for example:

```
#example-pageid footer {
               background:transparent;
                 }

#example-pageid {
            background_image:url(your/image/
            }
```

Comment: the footer shows in red. That means syntax error? I am a web dev noob still. I am still learning programming and taking some classes, but I havent learned CSS yet and I need to just get this site going for now. Thats why I used wordpress haha. site is chollimacoffee.co. It was actually unpublished but I just published it so you guys can help me.

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE**

Add following code to the bottom of your **avada-1035.css** ([here is the path](http://www.chollimacoffee.co/wp-content/uploads/avada-styles/avada-1035.css)):

```
#wrapper {
    background-image: url(../2016/12/Green-Background-PC-Free-Download.jpg);
}
```

Comment: chollimacoffee.co .. My current CSS is:                                                                      @media only screen and (max-width: 800px){
.mySep {
    margin-top: 200px !important
}
}

/* fixing jumping side navigation */
#side-header {
Position: fixed !important;
}

#page-id-1035 footer {
               background:transparent;
                 }

#page-id-1035 {
            background_image:url(http://www.chollimacoffee.co/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/Green-Background-PC-Free-Download.jpg)
            }

Comment: @Reed33 I have updated css (see above). please put it into avada-1035.css located in uploads folder.